# signalR no element found error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

On pages that I have signalR included I get the following error in firebug:

```
http://localhost:53604/signalr/signalr/negotiate?_=1352797361490
no element found
```

everything still works fine but just wanted to see if this will become an issue. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Firebug that means you're using Firefox.  What transport are you using (if using Fiddler remember to turn Streaming on)?  It should be:
1. Long Polling
2. Server Sent Events
3. WebSockets

If the transport is Long Polling then we probably have an issue in the underlying code(Firefox should prioritize WebSockets/SSE before LP).

However, if not then we have a content based issue.  So that being said, what type of data are you retrieving from the server?  Usually a no element found error comes from invalid markup.

Try stripping out all pieces of your application and see if you still get this error.  AKA just a $.connection.hub.start().

Comment: this is weird because when I remove signalR reference I don't get that error message anymore.

Comment: 'no element found' usually originates from faulty content getting send over the wire so that would make sense if you remove SignalR, aka you're no longer sending any data in real time.

Comment: Also getting this, even with just a $.connection.hub.start()